# Help with command to teleport NPCs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/tp @e[name=Farmer,type=ArmorStand] @e[name=Farmer,type=Villager]
```

Why doesn't it work? I've tried spacing things out, but it just refuses to work! Interestingly, if i just do `/tp @e[type=ArmorStand] @e[type=Villager]` it will work properly. Sorry if I haven't given enough info.

Answer (score -1):

Oh nevermind it was the clock i ran it on.

Comment: You might want to add a bit more of an explanation. What specifically was wrong with the clock?

Comment: Clock as in in-game or as in a prefab?